# How to get rid of git comments which are displayed by VS Code above certain source code lines?

Tags: visual-studio-code

VS Code for some reason displays some sort of clickable information above some of the lines in every source code file, indicating the author name and "how long ago" (probably how long ago a change in the code below was committed by the specified author).

I'm not sure if it's some extension, but I've uninstalled the only one I had with the name 'git' being a part of it.

Does anybody have an idea how I can get rid of these comments or notification or whatever they are?

Comment: search settings for `lens`

Comment: @rioV8: Can you be a little more clear please? What does "search settings" mean?

Comment: open the settings GUI and type `lens`

Comment: Tx, solved it (I think, let's see if those nasty comments don't popup again)

Answer (score 0):

Solved by clicking `Code` at the top-left part of the window, then `Settings`, then `Settings...`, then typing `lens author` in the search-box, then unchecking the following two check-boxes:

[image]